# How do I log in as non-interactive user? (e.g. mysql)

Tags: users

I need to run a command `mysql_upgrade` which, when ran as root, returns

```
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: '--port=3306' '--socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' 
mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

So I decided I need to log in as user `mysql`. How can I do it?

I set up the password for the user `mysql` with `passwd` and try to log in:

```
$ ssh -l mysql 12.34.56.78
mysql@12.34.56.78's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I logged in as root and set shell for `mysql` with `chsh -s /bin/bash mysql`.
I checked that `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`'s `AllowUsers` entry contains user `mysql` and `DenyGroups` contains only `deniedssh`; the latter group doesn't contain user `mysql`:

```
# getent group deniedssh
deniedssh:x:500:
```

What can I do to log in as the non-interactive user `mysql`?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is flawed, you do not need to log in on the shell as the mysql user. The authentication failures you see come from mysqld, you need to tell `mysql_upgrade` which username and password to use to talk to mysql, unix authentication is not involved at all here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common use case for `sudo`, which allows you to run commands (depending on configuration even a shell) as any user your system administrator has granted you to become (not only `root`, as most novices might think).

Depending on your `sudo` configuration you might be able to just do

```
$ sudo -s -u mysql
```

as your »normal« user account.  You can check which users you are allowed to become by issuing

```
$ sudo -l
```

This could look like the following (my local installation and my »normal« user):

```
$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for aw on swiftsure:
    env_keep+=HOME, env_keep+=XDG_SESSION_COOKIE, env_keep+="XMODIFIERS GTK_IM_MODULE QT_IM_MODULE QT_IM_SWITCHER", insults, tty_tickets, editor=/usr/bin/vim, !lecture

Runas and Command-specific defaults for aw:
    Defaults>root targetpw, env_file=/etc/sudo/root.env

User aw may run the following commands on swiftsure:
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/htop, /usr/sbin/iotop, /usr/sbin/powertop
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/wpa_cli
$
```

The last lines are the important ones.  In this example case, it tells that user `aw` may run every command (`ALL`) as every user (`(ALL)`) and `htop`, `iotop`, `powertop`, and `wpa_cli` as every user (`(ALL)`) without needing to give a password (`NOPASSWD`).

If you're user has an entry `(ALL) ALL` you're fine and just can issue the above command to become the user `mysql`.  If not, you might want to edit your `/etc/sudoers` file (`visudo`) and add a line containing

```
username      (ALL)=ALL
```

which would allow you to become *every* user (after typing `username`'s password) or something like

```
username      (mysql)=ALL
```

which would only allow you to become the `mysql` user.